# Why Rails redirects to the /create page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the next create action in feed_controller:

```
def create
  @feed = Feed.new(check_params)
  @new_feed = Feed.new(check_params)
  @feed.member_id = current_user.member.id

  if params[:commit] == "Upload Video"
    if @feed.save
      now_is = User.select("uploadLimit").where("email" => session[:email]).last.uploadLimit
      User.update(session[:id], :uploadLimit => now_is.to_i - 1)
      redirect_to "/#{params[:locale]}/feed"
      flash[:notice] = "Congratulations! Your media file has been added!"
    else
      redirect_to "/#{params[:locale]}/feed"
      flash[:notice] = "Oops! Something went wrong!"
    end
  end
end
```

And my routes.rb is:

```
post '/:locale/feed/create', to: "feed#create"
get '/:locale/feed/new', to: "feed#new", as: 'feed_new'
```

So, my question is, why it redirects to the /create but not to the `redirect_to "/#{params[:locale]}/feed` page? It works yesterday, but today I'm checking now it ceased to work. Who knows, what is the problem?

Comment: That would happen if `if params[:commit] == "Upload Video"` fails.

Comment: Also you don't have a route for `"/:locale/feed"`

Comment: What error are you seeing? The Rails console should be showing something.

Comment: Can you show the form and/or the console log that shows the incoming params? I'm guessing that the if params[:commit] line is hitting false, and defaulting to rendering create.html.erb.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure that your flash setters need to come before your redirect_tos, since I believe redirect "short circuits" the method. I doubt that's what's causing the mis-rendering.